# .net Core EF Linq select where between two dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am migrating an existing MVC5 project to .net Core.  I used the following to get a list of items between two dates:

```
var result = _context.Model.Where(c => c.ID == ID)
             .Where(c=> c.Day >= fromDate)
             .Where(c => c.Day <= toDate).Select(model => new
            {
                Item1 = model.Item1
                Item2 = mdoel.Item2
            }).OrderBy(c => c.Day);
```

It works in MVC5 but not in core I get:

```
Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"
```

It works if I remove Where(c=> c.Day >= fromDate)?

Is there any special for greater than or equal in EF core?

Comment: Are you sure that same table content used? If one query works in standard EF but not in EF Core, possibly the result set has changed (grab & try to run same query in SQL), hence `.Where(c=> c.Day >= fromDate)` condition doesn't yield any results anymore.

Comment: If you're getting that error, it simply means that the enumerable has no items. The query is simply filtering out everything, so nothing is being returned. Either your query is incorrect or the data you think is in the database is in fact not there.

Comment: Thank you Tetsuya and Chris, I was using  DateTime fromDate = toDate.AddMonths(-1).  There were no data, will try to figure out a better way to set fromDate.

Comment: can use this as Query   

 var result = _context.Model
                 .Where(c=> c.Day >= fromDate && c => c.Day 
                  <= toDate && c => c.ID == ID))
                 .Select(model => new
                {
                    Item1 = model.Item1
                    Item2 = mdoel.Item2
                }).OrderBy(c => c.D)